# Clock drift windows 7 in to the future

Tags: windows-7, windows, clock

I am running windows 7 and from the time I bought the pc it has always had clock issue. My computer is constantly going in to the future, faster while a sleep (can sometimes be an hour or more) but while awake it runs maybe 1-5 min faster per 10 min. Seams to be no pattern. I have taken the computer to the shop and they see nothing wrong with the setup. Under linux it runs like a clock and the bios clock appears to be working on the right time. It is only under Windows things are going in to the future all the time. I have synced to the internet time, turned it off, changed time zone, daylight savings on/off, chanted Indian songs while drinking goat blood under a full moon while holding the computer but nothings seams to work.

I am very frustrated and feel very alone :( Any ideas would be appreciated. This desktop pc was assembled for me by a local computer store.

while writing this the computer has gone 10 min in to the future. Maybe I should let it drift alot and check out the next Saturday's lottery numbers?

I would like to add I can see the second hand moving way to fast and it takes 30 sec to go one minute.

**Update:** 
I found  [one solution which looks promising](http://makingwindowseasy.com/2011/09/02/help-windows-7-system-clock-is-running-fast/)  but I get the following errors when running the following commands.

*Net stop w32time*

The service name is invalid.

--- and then later ----

*net start w32time*

The service start failed since on or more services in the same process have an incompatible service SID type setting. A service with restritced service SID type can only coexist in the same process with other services with a restricted SID type. If the service SID type for this service was sjust configured, the hosting process must be restared in order to start this service.

Any thoughts?

**update**

Well folks, I would like to thank you all who responded to my question. It turned out my mother board was faulty. It failed on me a few days ago while I was trying to fix the clock problem. The company I bought the pc from replaced the motherboard fee of charge and guess what. The clock problem is gone. The pc clock is now running correctly. So problem solved. Again thanks for your help folks.

Greetings from Iceland
Birgir.

---

How the heck do you mark this as solved?

**Update 19. jan 2014**
I was asked if I could clarify why the the pc ran the  clock correctly while running linux live cd. I can't really answer that since I didn't try it my self. But the repair guy's said the clock ran normal under Linux. I do remember the clock did run normally at first and than gradually the clock problem got worse. But sometimes it improved. The motherboard must have been coming in and out of "face" or what ever. At least that is the only thing I can think off.

I didn't try using the NTP client and I am not sure if it would have solved all my problems even if it would have made the pc in sync. The clock would still run 50% to fast though it would have been re synced every minuet. For example the latest vlc didn't play video correctly and it appear to try to run the video at double speed just like my clock was running.

Comment: Have you researched anything online about this? I found a lot of possible fixes with a Google search for "windows 7 clock too fast".

Comment: chanted Indian songs while drinking goat blood under a full moon while holding the computer but nothings seams to work.   LOL

Comment: @CharlieRB gives good advice. Also, I love how expressive you are with this question.

Comment: Well now I look like I didn't do my homework before postin :(. I did do a Google search but that was about 1 year ago and couldn't find anything useful at the time. And the problem wasn't as obvious as now. But I am going through the list of google search like CharlieRB suggested. Tried one result. So far no luck. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Please ensure that you're not moving close to the speed of light. Avoid intimate encounters with black holes and neutron stars.

Comment: I am not stupid, I of course make sure I don't go over 88mph when driving with the computer from the shop and home.

Comment: mark it as solved by posting an answer to your own question (you may need to wait a day or two before you can mark your answer as the correct answer)

Comment: You say that you have synced to the Internet time, but have you tried running an NTP client that could keep your machine synced?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a dirty but effective solution?

1. Go here, [NTPSync](http://www.m-tecs.net/?a=products&b=win&c=en)
2. Download NTPsync 1.0 and install
3. Win7
   Clock Properties -> Internet Time -> Change Settings -> Disable
   "Synchronize with an Internet time server"
4. List item open NTPSync, set sync
   every 1 min, choose a valid NTP server (time.ien.it works for me but
   there are a ton on google)
5. Save settings, Hide, Run on startup

headaches solved

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The mother board was faulty.

Comment: Can you explain how Linux was able to make the faulty mother board run correctly?

Comment: @Scott Maybe Linux had NTP client installed keeping system time correct (and OP didn't check if HW clock was kept in sync with system time or not)...